# Filtering a binary matrix to only contain groups that meet a minimum size

Tags: python, matrix

I am given an arbitrary binary matrix of the form:

```
Input = [
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,0],
[1,0,0,0,1]
]
```

My objective is to filter this binary matrix so it only contains "islands" of size n or bigger. I am only searching horizontally and not wrapping around matrix edges. If for example, I wanted islands of size 2 or bigger, the output would be:

```
Output = [
[0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to set this problem up. I know I need to do to a nested for loop to search through but I don't know how to generalize this problem so it works for any size island or any arbitrary matrix. The first thought that came to mind was DFS but I am not too sure how to implement DFS with a minimum island condition. Also I am only searching horizontally, not vertically and not wrapping around matrix edges. Any thoughts or tips on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're searching horizontally only, you can split the problem by row and filter each row separately (array)

Comment: yeah I did that, basically loop by value then loop by index to go row by row. My issue is ensuring that an island is of sufficient size and if it isn't, then back tracking to remove the 1 and replace with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what does my solution (not sure it is exactly what you're expecting) :

• Keeps any row having at least one island and discards others

• Accepts several islands in a same row

• Sets any column not member of an island to zero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 6
#define ISLAND 2

void printMatrix(char matrix[SIZE][SIZE], char limit) {
    for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) { 
        for (int j=0; j<SIZE; j++) { 
            printf("%d,", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    
    // Fills a matrix with random 1 and 0 and prints it
    srand(time(NULL));
    char matrix[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE*SIZE; i++) { matrix[i/SIZE][i%SIZE] = (char)(rand() % 2); }
    printMatrix(matrix, SIZE);

    // The matching rows will be copied in a second matrix
    char result[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
    char resultCount = 0;
    
    // Filtering
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        bool found = false;
        char start = -1;
        for (int j=0; j<SIZE; j++) { 
            if (matrix[i][j]) {
                start = j;
                while (j < SIZE && matrix[i][j]) j++;
                if (j - start >= ISLAND) found = true;
                else for (char k=start; k<j; k++) matrix[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            memcpy(result + resultCount, matrix[i], SIZE);
            resultCount++;
        }
    }
    //Prints the result
    printf("%d row(s) found :\n", resultCount);
    printMatrix(result, resultCount);
    return 0;
}
```